# how to apply crossover and mutation rates in genetic algorithm?

Tags: genetic-algorithms, heuristics, genetic-programming, genetic-operators

I'm working with genetic programming and let's say I have the following operator:

- pop_size = 100
- Crossover ratio = 0.4
- Mutation Ratio = 0.2
- Selection Ratio = 0.1

What is exactly the next generation will look like?

- Select 10% from the last pop with any selection scheme.
- Fill 40% of the next generation with the crossover between parents.
- Mutate the new offspring based on that mutation ratio before adding it to the next generation.
- That will be 50% of the next generation filled up, and we have to fill the remaining 50%, how to do this? by mutating the individuals from the last generation according to the mutation ratio? add some random genes to the next generation?

Answer (score 1):

The remaining will be models selected from the original population based on the best performers (or some other user defined criteria).  You don't do anything to those models - no crossover and no mutations - just keep them as they are.

Comment: so first of all we gonna select 10% with any selected method, after that, we gonna fill the remaining 50% of the next generation with the old individuals' best performers; if we sum this we gonna find 60% of the last individuals will be added to the next generation?